# Ionic/Phonegap+LinkedInOAuth: Getting an error "unable to verify access_token" on mobile while web oauth works fine

Tags: cordova, oauth, linkedin-api, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build an Ionic/Phonegap app, and I would like to authenticate against LinkedIn using OAuth. On the web, I go to `http://localhost:8080/api/login` and it takes me through the OAuth dance, but on the mobile I get the following error:

```
{
  errorCode: 0, 
  message: "Unable to verify access token", 
  requestId: "AVY9SG1I4I", 
  status: 401, 
  timestamp: 1422647386788
}
```

Here are some observations I made from testing various scenarios:

1. Multiple logins to `/api/login` seem ok on the web (Chrome)
2. I have only ever got an authenticated resource from the response once when going through the Phonegap InAppBrowser. The other 20 odd times it gives the error above.
3. Once I get the error on the mobile, the web starts throwing the above error as well, for about 5-10 minutes. After 5-10 minutes, it starts returning the correct authenticated results.

I am wondering if this has something to do with starting up an InAppBrowser every time which LinkedIn does not like?

On the client side:

```
.controller('SignInCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

  $scope.signIn = function(user) {
    console.log('Sign-In', user);
    window.open(
      'http://localhost:8080/api/login', '_blank', 'location=yes');
  };

})
```

On the server side, its a Google App Engine app using webapp2:

```
def get(self):
        auth_code = self.request.params["code"]
        #tokens = step2_exchange(auth_code)
        http = httplib2.Http()
        resp, tokens = http.request(
            "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&code="+ auth_code +"&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flinkedinoauthcallback", 
            method='POST')
        tokens = json.loads(tokens)
        pdb.set_trace()
        print tokens
        http = httplib2.Http()
        headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer' + tokens['access_token']}
        resp, content = http.request("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections?modified=new&format=json", method='GET', headers=headers)
        print content
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        self.response.write(json.dumps(content))
```

Comment: I actually made a library that will accomplish this for you.  You may want to check it out. https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth

Comment: Hey Nic, tried your lib and I get the same error from ionic. Additionally, I needed the access token on the server to make calls from my server (App Engine) since the client is in a bandwidth constrained env. Leaving that aside however, I still see the error on my Ionic app. Here is the corresponding code (didn't know how to get better formatting in the comments):

Comment: ```$scope.getMyToken = function() {

    $scope.authToken = AuthTokenFactory.getToken();

    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer " + window.localStorage.getItem("access_token");

    $http.get("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json")
            .success(function(data) {

                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            });
  };
})```

Comment: ```.controller('SignInCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaOauth, $http, AuthTokenFactory) {
  
  $scope.signIn = function(user) {
    console.log('Sign-In', user);
    // window.open(
    //   'http://localhost:8080/api/login', '_blank', 'location=yes');
    //$state.go('tab.dash');
    $cordovaOauth.linkedin("CL-ID", "CL-SECRET", ["r_basicprofile"], "state")
    .then(function(result) {
      AuthTokenFactory.setToken(result['access_token']);
      $state.go('tab.account');
    }, function (error) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    })
  };
  
})```

Comment: And I made the callback url: ```http://localhost/callback```
as you mentioned in the docs. I do see an access_token at the end of the first step, its only when I use the access_token to make the GET request does it tell me "Invalid access token" error. Any reason you can see this happening/ how can I debug this further?
ps: its "Invalid access token" now as opposed to "Unable to verify access token"

Comment: I don't know what AuthTokenFactory is, but maybe your back-end is calling some kind of invalidate on the access token?

Comment: AuthTokenFactory is just a getter/setter to the localStorage:
```.service('AuthTokenFactory', function AuthTokenFactory($window) {
  'use strict';

  var store = $window.localStorage;
  var key = 'auth-token';
  return {
    getToken: getToken,
    setToken: setToken
  }

  function getToken() {
    return store.getItem(key);
  }

  function setToken(token) {
    if (token) {
      store.setItem(key, token);
    } else {
      store.removeItem(key);
    }
  }
})```

I don't have a backend at present, I'm just using your library with Ionic.

Comment: Btw, is there any other settings on the LinkedIn page that needs to be set apart from the redirect urls? Like the "Javascript Domain APIs"? Didn't seem to think so because I am not using their Javascript APIs.

Comment: If you're able to get an access token, it means everything is good.  Are you sure are requesting the appropriate application scopes for the APIs you want to use?